# WCF Error message 'The requested Performance Counter is not a custom counter, it has to be initialized as ReadOnly'

Tags: wcf, enterprise-library-4.1

I received following error message, while invoke my WCF Function

```
The requested Performance Counter is not a custom counter, it has to be initialized as ReadOnly
at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter.InitializeImpl()
   at System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter..ctor(String categoryName, String counterName, String instanceName, Boolean readOnly)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Instrumentation.EnterpriseLibraryPerformanceCounterFactory.CreateCounter(String categoryName, String counterName, String[] instanceNames)
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.PolicyInjection.CallHandlers.PerformanceCounterCallHandler.Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
   at Example.SoaPlatform.LoggingService.Client.LogTraceCallHandler.Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextHandlerDelegate getNext)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.HandlerPipeline.Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, InvokeHandlerDelegate target)
   at Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.InterceptingRealProxy.Invoke(IMessage msg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&amp; msgData, Int32 type)
   at Example.Mobiliti.MobilitiAlertService.ContractTypes.IMobilitiAlertService.SendSMSAlert(SendSmsAlertRequest request)
   at SyncInvokeSendSMSAlert(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]&amp; outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace>
```

I ran the following commands, still the issue not yet resolved.

```
lodctr /R
cd C:\Windows\Inf\.NETFramework
lodctr corperfmonsymbols.ini
```

Enterprise Library version is 4.1.0, I checked through file properties

Comment: Have you tried running Visual Studio as administrator?

Comment: Yes. Visual studio ran in administrator mode

Comment: Have you tried running InstallServices.bat? Location: c:\program files\microsoft enterprise library 5.0\InstallServices.bat"https://serverfault.com/a/340122